# How to Convert selected date to standard date after selection in Jquery UI DatePicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have localized version of JQueryUI DatePicker integrated in my project.it works well.but now i want when user selects a date in my custom culture the date showing in the `input` field be in standard format.because i planed to store it in a database table.and i don't like to add date conversion overload to my application.

my DatePicker integration code :

```
 $('#PublishDate').datepicker({

 });
```

Comment: Show us the code that you use for the datepicker.

Comment: there is nothing more than simple integration.

Comment: $('#PublishDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })

Comment: it show me the local date ("19-06-1391" in persian date)

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`this for setting the date format....

```
//getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );

//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

alternatively you can also implement the select event

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```

and writer your code for changing the date format in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like :

```
$('#PublishDate').datepicker({            
'altField' => '#PublishDateH',
'altFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',    
});
```

and create one hidden element `PublishDateH` that you can store in database

Comment: thank you all for response.i can't do this, there is couple of code to change for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use:

`$('#element').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });`

Or even better open the culture your using and editing the `dateFormat` there.

Comment: i have used this :  $.datepicker.regional['fa'].dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd"; but still getting local date

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili then just change the dateFormat in your culture file.

Comment: i have checked culture file.and format is just like suggested by you.but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set the culture according to whatever locale you need, like this..

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']); // for English-UK
```

Set it to whatever you need as per your case. More details [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization).